# PIG need to find max

Tags: apache-pig

I am new to Pig and working on a problem where I need to find the the player in this dataset with the max weight. Here is a sample of the data:

```
  id,     weight,id,year, triples
(bayja01,210,bayja01,2005,6)
(crawfca02,225,crawfca02,2005,15)
(damonjo01,205,damonjo01,2005,6)
(dejesda01,190,dejesda01,2005,6)
(eckstda01,170,eckstda01,2005,7)
```

and here is my pig script:

```
batters = LOAD 'hdfs:/user/maria_dev/pigtest/Batting.csv' using PigStorage(',');
realbatters = FILTER batters BY $1==2005;
triphitters = FILTER realbatters BY $9>5;
tripids =  FOREACH triphitters GENERATE $0 AS id,$1 AS YEAR, $9 AS Trips;
names = LOAD 'hdfs:/user/maria_dev/pigtest/Master.csv' 
using PigStorage(',');
weights = FOREACH names GENERATE $0 AS id, $16 AS weight;
get_ids = JOIN  weights BY (id), tripids BY(id);
wts  = FOREACH get_ids GENERATE MAX(get_ids.weight)as wgt;
DUMP wts;
```

the second to last line did not work of course. It told me  I had to use an explicit cast. I have the filtering etc figured out - jsut can't figure out how to get the final answer.

Comment: I tried this and aI am still getting the 1045 error:                                                                                  id_wght = FOREACH names GENERATE $0 AS id, (double)$16 AS weight;
get_ids = JOIN  id_wght BY (id), tripids BY(id);
final = FOREACH get_ids GENERATE MAX($1),$0 AS id;

Answer (score 0):

The `MAX` function in Pig expects a Bag of values and will return the highest value in the bag. In order to create a Bag, you must first `GROUP` your data:

```
get_ids = JOIN weights BY id, tripids BY id;

-- Drop columns we no longer need and rename for ease

just_ids_weights = FOREACH get_ids GENERATE
    weights::id AS id,
    weights:: weight AS weight;

-- Group the data by id value

gp_by_ids = GROUP just_ids_weights BY id;

-- Find maximum weight by id

wts = FOREACH gp_by_ids GENERATE 
   group AS id,
   MAX(just_ids_weights.weight) AS wgt;
```

If you wanted the maximum weight in all of the data, you can put all of your data in a single bag using `GROUP ALL`:

```
gp_all = GROUP just_ids_weights ALL;

was = FOREACH gp_all GENERATE
    MAX(just_ids_weights.weight) AS wgt;
```